# Function contains multiple control flow statements

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

- I wrote a code for a 3x3 bingo game. It check for line, bingo or nothing for a given input where I get a 3x3 bingo card and next 15 numbers extracted.
- Basically I use a 2D user inputed array for the 3x3 bingo card, then I have a function which asks me to input 15 numbers. If all the numbers from the 3x3 bingo card are present in those 15 extracted numbers then I have "bingo". If I have numbers from a line but not all numbers then the program will output "line". And if i will not have bingo neither line the program will output "nothing".
- I don't like the CheckForLine() function using 3 nested loops. I can't use Linq, due to Sonar analyzer limitation.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        const int numberOfRows = 3;
        const int numberOfColumnns = 3;
        const int numbersExtracted = 15;
        int[,] bingoCard = ReadBingoCard(numberOfRows, numberOfColumnns);
        int[] numbers = ReadNumbersExtracted(numbersExtracted);
        PrintResult(bingoCard, numbers);
    }

    static int[,] ReadBingoCard(int rowsNumber, int columnNumber)
    {
        int[,] card = new int[rowsNumber, columnNumber];

        for (int i = 0; i < rowsNumber; i++)
        {
            string[] array = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

            for (int j = 0; j < columnNumber; j++)
            {
                card[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(array[j]);
            }
        }

        return card;
    }

    static int[] ReadNumbersExtracted(int numbersExtracted)
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[numbersExtracted];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbersExtracted; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        return numbers;
    }

    static bool CheckForBingo(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbers)
    {
        int numMatchesFound = 0;
        foreach (var number in bingoCard)
        {
            for (int numIndex = 0; numIndex < numbers.Length; numIndex++)
            {
                if (number == numbers[numIndex])
                {
                    numMatchesFound++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return numMatchesFound == bingoCard.Length;
    }

    static bool CheckForLine(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbers)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < bingoCard.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            int colMatchesInRow = 0;

            for (int col = 0; col < bingoCard.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                for (int numIndex = 0; numIndex < numbers.Length; numIndex++)
                {
                    if (bingoCard[row, col] != numbers[numIndex])
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    colMatchesInRow++;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (colMatchesInRow == bingoCard.GetLength(1))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    static void PrintResult(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbersExtracted)
    {
        if (CheckForBingo(bingoCard, numbersExtracted))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bingo");
        }
        else if (CheckForLine(bingoCard, numbersExtracted))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("line");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("nothing");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I can't use Linq, due to Sonar analyzer limitation." That doesn't really tell us much. What happens if you try? (`bingoCard.Intersect(numbers).Count()` seems pretty simple to me...)

Comment: Bcs of didactic considerations, I can't use Linq. Sonar won't let me compile "S134 (Error) : Refactor this code to not nest more than 3 control flow statements. "

Comment: "Bcs of didactic considerations" - which you won't go into any more details of? How are we meant to suggest changes when you won't provide details of the constraints? What's forcing you to use Sonar?

Comment: The platform on which I`ll upload the solution won`t accept it without sonar.

Comment: So put that into the question - but with far more detail (e.g. what the platform is, what the Sonar rules etc). We shouldn't be having to ask for every scrap of relevant information in multiple comments.

Comment: I don`t think that those are relevant info (what is the platform). I asked a simple question of how a function could be reshaped without using Linq, and not having more than 3 nested statements.

Comment: So you don't think it's relevant info if someone proposes an answer that you could immediately find out is not going to help you, by virtue of constraints that *you* know but haven't shared? But if you don't feel like providing that information, no-one can force you to. You're just less likely to get an answer if people feel (as I do) that you're not providing enough information.